# didUpdateToLocation alert called only twice

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Suppose in the starting the location services are off in the default settings page. I have a button in the app to turn on the location services if first time I click on that it shows the default alert to change the settings to turn on

```
    locationmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationmanager setDelegate:self];
    [locationmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];
```

It is working fine two times. but if it got third time location services are in off condition and click on on button it doesn't show any alert. I am unable to know the CLLocation behavior. May b its not a good question to ask but still I want to clear this concept. if anyone has some idea then please help me out.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) says:

> In addition to hardware not being available, the user has the option of denying an application’s access to location service data. During its initial uses by an application, the Core Location framework prompts the user to confirm that using the location service is acceptable. If the user denies the request, the `CLLocationManager` object reports an appropriate error to its delegate during future requests. You can also check the application’s explicit authorization status using the `authorizationStatus` method.

So the alert could or could not appear, based on `authorizationStatus`.